# Numerical digitize give a stack trace error on all releases after 3.18

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, attributeerror

I use the numerical digitize plugin often and it no longer functions in versions of QGIS released after 3.18. Please help or offer another option.

The error is as follows

```
2023-03-25T14:42:28     WARNING    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jasonowsley/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/numericalDigitize/numericalDigitize.py", line 194, in run
  self.__dlg.configureDialog(self.__layergeometryType, self.__layerwkbType, self.__isMultiType,
  File "/home/jasonowsley/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/numericalDigitize/addFeatureGUI.py", line 210, in configureDialog
  self.twPoints.setColumnWidth(i, self.twPoints.width()/self.twPoints.columnCount())
 TypeError: setColumnWidth(self, int, int): argument 2 has unexpected type 'float'
```

In addition, under the processing tab I see this:

```
2023-03-25T14:42:15     CRITICAL    Problem with OTB installation: OTB folder is not set.
2023-03-25T14:42:15     CRITICAL    Problem with SAGA installation: SAGA was not found or is not correctly installed
```

Comment: I've changed the title (2.18 -> 3.18). Should it be 2.18? What did you mean, 2.18 or 3.18?

Comment: yes i meant 3.18 thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess you found a bug. For a temporary solution, you can try the follows:

1. Go to the plugin folder (Settings > User Profiles > Open Active Profile Folder, and navigate to `python` > `plugins` > `numericalDigitize`)
2. Open `addFeatureGUI.py`. Find the line starting with `self.twPoints.setColumnWidth(...` (Line 210).

   [image]
3. Change `self.twPoints.width()/self.twPoints.columnCount()` to `int(self.twPoints.width()/self.twPoints.columnCount())`

   [image]

The problem is that a float value is passed to the `setColumnWidth` function. However, it has to be an integer value.

From [Documentation](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsAttributeTableConfig.html#adb48e1ece6d511066d33656c60cdc147):

> `setColumnWidth()`
> `void QgsAttributeTableConfig::setColumnWidth(int column, int width)`

Comment: That's great it took care of the issue.